# How to configure nodejs build plugin inside Sublime Text 3

Tags: node.js, sublimetext3

I am trying to configure this plugin:
https://github.com/tanepiper/SublimeText-Nodejs
in Sublime Text 3.

I have this settings as a default ones:

```
{
  // save before running commands
  "save_first": true,
  // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
  // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
  "node_command": false,
  // Same for NPM command
  "npm_command": false,
  // as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
  "node_path": true,

  "expert_mode": false,

  "output_to_new_tab": false
}
```

And then I have my user setting:

```
{
  "node_path": "C:/Program Files/nodejs/"
}
```

I also checked and I have node in the Path, that can be accessed globally. I use Windows 10, and still, the output shows that this plugin cannot find node.exe:

> ERROR: The process "node.exe" not found. module.js:557
>       throw err;
>       ^

Can somebody help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NODE_PATH` is using for setting paths where Nodejs will search modules to import in your code (see: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders)

If you want to set path to the Nodejs executable you should use `node_command` option instead of `node_path`. Also, on Windows you should you use backslash as path separator NOT forward slash.